# How can I get this grid not to resize?

Tags: html, css, image, grid, gallery

I found the image grid below (link) that i am using however currently when the grid resizes the squares get smaller, i'd like it so the squares fall below each other rather than resize. How is this possible? i've tried adding floats and adjusting widths but i'm obviously missing something stupid?

[link](https://codepen.io/uargh/pen/IiyGu)

CSS

```
.container {
 border: 1px solid #fff;

ul {
   display: block;
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
}

li {
   box-sizing: border-box;
   display: block;
   float: left;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
   padding-bottom: 33.3%;
   width: 33.3%;

   background-color: #000;
   border: 2px solid #fff;

&:hover {
  h3 {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out .1s;
  }
  img {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

h3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  min-height: 3em;
  padding: 15px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 10;

  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .65), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
 }

img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  max-height: 110%;
  max-width: 110%;
  opacity: .7;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 0;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `height` and `width` in `px` and set `display:inline-block` to `.container li`

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
.container ul {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.container li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}
.container li:hover h3 {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out .1s;
}
.container li:hover img {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
.container li h3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  min-height: 3em;
  padding: 15px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 10;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65), transparent);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  margin: 0;
}
.container li img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  max-height: 110%;
  max-width: 110%;
  opacity: .7;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h3>Item Number One</h3>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/650/650/abstract/7/" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>Item Number One</h3>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/650/650/abstract/1/" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>Item Number One</h3>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/650/650/abstract/3/" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>Item Number One</h3>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/650/650/abstract/5/" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>Item Number One</h3>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/650/650/abstract/6/" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>Item Number One</h3>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/650/650/abstract/8/" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>Item Number One</h3>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/650/650/abstract/9/" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>Item Number One</h3>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/650/650/abstract/10/" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>Item Number One</h3>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/650/650/fashion/2/" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```